# GFORTRAN_1.4 Not Found

Tags: python, ipython, enthought, canopy

After some fixing my PATH variable to get some library installs to work , I'm finding that my IPython Notebook (Enthought Canopy on Ubuntu 14.04) throws the following error when using the %matplotlib magic command:

```
ImportError: /home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/../lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3)
```

I'm also getting this error when trying to install python-bio-formats, pims, and pylibtiff.

Again, any ideas are appreciated.

EDIT: Full error traceback:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3042faeb62d7> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib')
      2 #import cv2
      3 #import numpy as np
      4 #import pandas as pd
      5 #import os

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
   2203         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2204         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2205         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2206 
   2207     #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2124                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2125             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2126                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2127             return result
   2128 

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    194 
    195         if callable(arg):

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)
     78         """
     79         args = magic_arguments.parse_argstring(self.matplotlib, line)
---> 80         gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
     81         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
     82 

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   2929         """
   2930         from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 2931         gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
   2932 
   2933         if gui != 'inline':

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
    250     """
    251 
--> 252     import matplotlib
    253 
    254     if gui and gui != 'auto':

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in <module>()
    177 # cbook must import matplotlib only within function
    178 # definitions, so it is safe to import from it here.
--> 179 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
    180 from matplotlib.compat import subprocess
    181 

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py in <module>()
     30 from weakref import ref, WeakKeyDictionary
     31 
---> 32 import numpy as np
     33 import numpy.ma as ma
     34 

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc in <module>()
    168         return loader(*packages, **options)
    169 
--> 170     from . import add_newdocs
    171     __all__ = ['add_newdocs',
    172                'ModuleDeprecationWarning',

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py in <module>()
     11 from __future__ import division, absolute_import, print_function
     12 
---> 13 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     14 
     15 ###############################################################################

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py in <module>()
     16 
     17 from . import scimath as emath
---> 18 from .polynomial import *
     19 #import convertcode
     20 from .utils import *

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in <module>()
     17 from numpy.lib.function_base import trim_zeros, sort_complex
     18 from numpy.lib.type_check import iscomplex, real, imag
---> 19 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
     20 
     21 class RankWarning(UserWarning):

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py in <module>()
     49 from .info import __doc__
     50 
---> 51 from .linalg import *
     52 
     53 from numpy.testing import Tester

/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in <module>()
     27     )
     28 from numpy.lib import triu, asfarray
---> 29 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
     30 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     31 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: /home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/../lib/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3)
```

Full PATH (from echo $PATH):

```
  /home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:
/usr/local/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/usr/bin:
/sbin:
/bin:
/usr/games:
/usr/local/games
```

sys.path:

```
 ['', '/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/src/svn', 
'/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pims', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python27.zip', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/home/joe/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', 
'/home/joe/opencv-2.4.9', 
'/home/joe/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.4.1.1975.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: What is the full error traceback, the full PATH (nicely formatted please), and the full sys.path (ditto)?

Comment: Edited to include full traceback, PATH, and sys.path output.

Comment: How did `/home/joe/opencv-2.4.9` get in there? Please search that dir (and its subdirs) to see if there is anything fortran-related.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'll have to remove that.  Meanwhile, running "find . -print | grep -i fort" in the opencv-2.4.9 directory returns nothing.

Comment: Following up on this, running sys.path.remove('/home/joe/opencv-2.4.9')  and then %matplotlib returns the same stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by following the steps outlined here (specifically, steps 3-5): https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy.

When re-attempting to install pims (https://github.com/soft-matter/pims) using pip (command: `pip install --upgrade http://github.com/soft-matter/pims/zipball/master`), the problem is able to be replicated.  Odd.

I'm also getting a problem when trying to install pylibtiff via its setup.py script, but I will post this in another SO post, further detailing the error.

Comment: Relaying a comment from a build expert: "This is caused by the user environment (PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH), and some packages built from source. For example, note how numpy here is linked against lapack in /usr/lib, which is not the case with Canopy's numpy."

Answer (score 0):

This might be late, but you can try the following thread

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/686

Specifically the one by Zarhid:

```
conda remove libgfortran
conda install libgcc --force
```

replace conda with pip and modify accordingly. Worked for me